# Windows 10 wifi connection to Iphone hotspot

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, connection

My laptop (Windows 10) only recognises my **iphone** hotspot (no problem with other wifi) if I turn off wifi on the laptop, turn the hotspot off and on then turn laptop wifi on. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the iPhone HotSpot and disconnect from existing wireless in one operation.

Be aware that if existing wireless is working well and iPhone gets wireless from the same point, that this may not work well. I have this here and have tried it.

With the same wireless signal, wireless will not disconnect to connect to iPhone.

You may try connecting your iPhone by USB and connecting that way.

For the most part, iPhone HotSpot is for areas and situations where the computer and iPhone are not competing for the same HotSpot.

This is entirely normal - nothing wrong.

[image]

Here is the iPhone connection (iPhone connected by USB to assure connection in spite of same common WiFi signal):

[image]